# PDO: PHP foreach array returning null

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, foreach

I did a very short and simple PHP .

The output is an array in json. However it doesn't work .

The array-items are always null.

I guess it must have something to do with mistakenly calling the db table columns

(`'id' => $row->MASTER_ID`).

Whereas '`MASTER_ID`' is the name of the column in my db.

I'd be very glad if someone could point me in the right direction. 
My script looks as follows:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx;dbname=xx;charset=utf8mb4', 'xx', 'xxx');
$month = date('Y-m');
$monthwild = "$month%";
$sql   = ("SELECT * FROM MASTER WHERE START_DATE LIKE '". $monthwild ."'");
$out = array();

foreach($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    $out[] = array(
        'id' => $row->MASTER_ID,
        'title' => $row->MASTER_TITLE,
        'start' => strtotime($row->MASTER_START),
        'end' => strtotime($row->MASTER_END)
    );
} 

echo json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'result' => $out));
exit;
?>
```

I'm new to PDO (used to do things like this with mysql) and

I didn't get it yet and didn't find the right resources

Comment: A very good tutorial: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: @DTH thanks, that looks good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDO::query` “executes an SQL statement, returning a **result set** as a PDOStatement object,” not a row.

You have to put the result in a variable and then retrieve rows from this variable:

```
$result = $db->query( $sql );
while( $row = $result->fetchObject() )
{
    (...)
}
```

As alternative, you can set a default fetch mode and then retrieve single rows with:

```
$result = $db->query( $sql );
$result->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
while( $row = $result->fetch() )
{
    (...)
}
```

---

#### Edit:

Actually, also direct `foreach` works, but without a specific fetch mode it returns enumerated and associative result:

```
foreach( $db->query( $sql ) as $row  )
{
    $id = $row['MASTER_ID'];
    // $id = $row[0]; // ← Alternative
}
```

To use objects with direct `foreach` you have to use this syntax:

```
foreach( $db->query( $sql, PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) as $row  )
{
    $id = $row->MASTER_ID;
}
```

---

- Read more about [PDO::query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)
- Read more about [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)

Comment: GREAT, thank you so much! This works perfectly!

I used the php example from bootstrap calendar https://github.com/Serhioromano/bootstrap-calendar hence i didn't question the foreach part :/

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that your definition of $monthwild is wrong.
The right notation for that what you want to write is:
$monthwild = $month."%";
In your script is the content of $monthwild the string "$month%"
Now is the content of $monthwild the string %

I hope you can understand that.
It is not easily described.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think i can follow - that makes sense and does seem more 'correct'. But actually `$monthwild = "$month%";` does work as intended too, don't ask me why - i just tried to code what seemed most obvious to a noob like i am :)